# How to set a <context-param> in Spring Boot without web.xml?

Tags: spring-boot, context-param

I have a Spring Boot application. I basically need to set the following context parameter:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But my Spring Boot application doesn't have a `web.xml`. How can I set it programmatically?

Comment: Do you geht the same exception for h:commandButton?

Comment: And this is a JSF thing, not a PrimeFaces thing!

Answer (score 0):

Following other posts, I added a `ServletContextInitializer` implementation.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigureJSFContextParameters implements ServletContextInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD", "client");

    }

}
```

Comment: Is this the JoinFaces way of doing it? I doubt, seems the plain servlet way of doing it. JSF in SpringBoot/JoinFaces is configured differently afaik (not using Spring here, never did)